# Use of Mechanize Library with Python 2.7 and Django

Tags: django, mechanize, mechanize-python

How do I use the mechanize library with Django?

I read online that I could put it in a directory (e.g. /lib/) and include as needed.

The problem is, the the source I had found didn't show how to use it from configuration to initial use. Unfortunately, I also looked high and low elsewhere on google with nothing to find. I also checked a book I have on django without any info..

Can anyone help me out?

I'm on a local install of django with python 2.7.

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "use the mechanize library with Django"?

Comment: How can I use the mechanize library with django. I cannot find out where to place the actual library or how to configure it

Comment: Use it for what? Writing test cases?

Comment: To use to capture information from a website

Comment: Installing it and doing `import mechanize` in your view does not work for you?

Comment: Do I install it to the python path?

Comment: @CodeTalk, you can install it different ways, try `pip install mechanize` then just open a python interpreter and `import mechanize` that should be it, you can start using mechanize in your Django project.

Answer (score 0):

As per comments, the answer is:

`pip install mechanize`

then just open a python interpreter and import mechanize to confirm.

That should be it, you can start using mechanize in your Django project.